# Intelligent Code Completion / Code Recommenders in Eclipse for 3rd party libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Where do you get [Code Recommenders](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/) recommendation models for [Intelligent Code Completion](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/#intelligent-code-completion) on 3rd party API's such as Spring, Hibernate, Junit, etc?

Intelligent Code Completion is meant to be used to learn unfamiliar libraries. To support this, it appears you need custom "models".

In their documentation this is stated [[source]](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/#overview):

> Code Recommenders automatically analyzes existing code using that API and extracts common usage rules and patterns from it. In the form of recommendation models, this knowledge is then fed back into your IDE.

And again later on [[source]](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/#models-preferences):

> Eclipse Code Recommenders relies on so-called model repositories to provide recommendation models for intelligent code completion and enhanced API documentation. You can add, edit, and remove model repositories on the Code Recommenders > Models preference page.

I can see in Ecplise Preferences how to add a model repository if I know its location. That is not the problem.
The problem is that I can't find any repositories of such models. Do they exist? Where can I find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plans to offer models for other frameworks in a marketplace. But that's not yet implemented. I'm not aware of companies that *publicly* offer recommendation models.

In which APIs would you be interested?

Comment: Apache-Commons, Guava, Junit, Mockito, Slf4j, Spring, Hibernate. I would think preference should essentially go to popularity. It would be nice for at least a few sample models to be in place so that users could get an idea of the power of the system and see if it is a worthwhile thing or not.

Comment: Are there any news concerning this feaure - _marketplace for other frameworks_?

Comment: Recently the source code miner powering Eclipse Code Recommenders has been released as part of an Eclipse IDE Tool Suite [1]. With that you can analyze any source code stored in your local Eclipse Workspace.

There is also an enterprise server available that is suitable to analyze arbitrary Maven or P2 code repositories. With that, building models for any library (and sharing its models) seems possible.

[1] https://ctrlflow.com/insights/enterprise/.